# Why not able to apply str.find_last_of( ) on const char * str

Tags: c++

I am just trying this code... I want to try to split my path as directory and file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void SplitFilename (const char * str)
{
  size_t found;
  cout << "Splitting: " << str << endl;
  found=str.find_last_of("//");
  cout << " folder: " << str.substr(0,found) << endl;
  cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << endl;
}

int main() {
    char *outFile1 = NULL;
    outFile1 = "//tmp//Softwares//v//vdisk";////tmp//iscsi//target1//lun1
    char* outFile2 = (char*) malloc(strlen(outFile1) + strlen(".meta") + 1);
    strcpy(outFile2,outFile1);
    strcat(outFile2, ".meta");
    cout << "str2:" << outFile2 << "\n";
    SplitFilename (outFile2);

}
```

and I am getting these errors

../src/test.cpp:20: error: request for member ‘find_last_of’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
../src/test.cpp:21: error: request for member ‘substr’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
../src/test.cpp:22: error: request for member ‘substr’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’

Can anyone tell me how can I make it work by passing a character pointer to the SplitFilename() function.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a character pointer into `SplitFilename()`? Just make it take a `std::string` instead.

Comment: And what's with all those `char`s and `malloc` in c++?  Just use a string, man!

Comment: Cause I want to perform the mkdir on the path that I obtain. mkdir doesn't work with a string argument,it wants a char* argument.

Comment: @vadugs:  check out the `c_str()` method of std::string.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 1):

str is a const char*. It is not a string.
char is a primitive type. Not an object.
I think you meant to convert str into an actual string object:

```
std::string my_string(str);
my_string.find_last_fo("//"):
.
.
.
```

Comment: If I convert char * into a String by giving void 
SplitFilename(const string& str)
it works... but i dont want to do that. I want to keep the data type as char *

Comment: Why though?  What do you gain from it?

Comment: I am trying to integrated it into a code, which actually wants the path as char * ... so I am trying to get it as char *

Comment: @vadugs: If you really need to keep it as a `char*` then maybe you should just be writing C? `strrchr()` will do what you want.

Comment: Cause I want to perform the mkdir on the path that I obtain. mkdir doesn't work with a string argument,it wants a char* argument.

Comment: @vadugs: No, it wants a `const char*` argument, which you can get from `std::string::c_str()`.